# Подключение к mysql из ide

Tags: java, mysql, битрикс, centos, jdbc

Хочу из ide работать с mysql сайта. Скачал образ для virtualbox VMBitrix, построенный на cent os, в нём поднял тестовый битриксовский шаблон, настроил статический ip адресс в системе, поставил phpmyadmin.

При попытке подкючения из ide падает ошибка Communication link failure. Пример как подключался ниже:

[image: пример подключения]

Comment: Непрошенный совет: сделайте mysqldump с боевой базы на сайте, разверните дамп на локальной тестовой базе - и на ней экспериментируйте. Хотя бы ради бэкапа сделайте дамп, пожалуйста.

Comment: Полагаю, что база просто не слушает внешние сетевые интерфейсы из соображений безопасности. Но это зависит от VM'ки, которую вы используете. Не зная, кто её делал и из каких соображений, строить предположения сложно.

Comment: @D-side а окно ide правильно заполнено host например ? коннектиться к ней по ip надо?

Comment: **Если я прав и БД не слушает внешних интерфейсов**, то неправильно. Ну... точнее, *настолько правильно, насколько позволяет ситуация*, но работать это не будет, если либо (а) не попросить БД слушать соединения снаружи (что опасно, т. к. легко дать слишком много доступа), либо (б) подсоединиться через тоннель (SSH?) так, чтобы для машины это соединение выглядело как соединение через локальную петлю.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно подключиться для начала к серверу с виртуалкой по `SSH`, а уже затем подключаться к локальной (с точки зрения виртуалки) базе. Через `PhpStorm` вы должны на вклдаке `SSH` прописать данные для подключения, а затем на основной вкладке вы подключаетесь к базе через `localhost`. Аналогично настраивается подлюкчение к базе в `MySQL Workbench`, сначала к серверу по `SSH`, затем через `localhost` к базе.